# Why is this form's request not working?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple login form I wish to have post to ASP.Net MVC. I've found that if the action is set to /Login it works. But if I write out the action name such as "/Login/Index" then it fails. The server returns a 302 back to the login page and the POST version of Index() is never called. Why is this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="/Login/Index/" method="post">

            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="60" />

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="20" />

            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
```

Here's the controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Here's the only route defined in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Movie", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Solved:**
In my Web.Config I had loginUrl="~/Login" and it needed to be "~/Login/Index" otherwise access was denied to the URL and it redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Is it possible that you've made the change to your view without rebuilding?

Comment: Monitor the activity client-side in something like Firebug.  It _should_ be performing a POST if the `method` is `post`, but it may immediately be getting redirected to something else.  There could be clues there.

Comment: Sorry Actually I see I am getting a POST but the server responds with a 302 back to the login. Why would the POST version of Index not be called though?

Comment: Are you sure that POST is not called? Did you put breakpoint on "return null" line to check?

Comment: Yes I did just that. It never gets called only the GET version that returns the view is called.

Comment: Solved it I think. In my Web.Config I had loginUrl="~/Login" and it needed to be "~/Login/Index" otherwise access was denied to the URL and it redirected back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

In my Web.Config I had `loginUrl="~/Login"` and it needed to be `"~/Login/Index"`. Because anonymous access is denied, any URL other than the one specified as the `loginURL` is denied and redirects back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

"/Login/Index" and "/Login/Index/" are distinct actions.  If you take out that trailing /, it may work the way you were expecting.

Comment: Same results either way. You're right, but the way MVC's routing works I'm almost certain they are not treated differently here.

Answer (score 0):

try adding [HttpGet] to the first method